# How do i remove gravatar completely from wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to to remove gravatar completely for my [website](https://dylogue.com/). I've already disabled gravatar on the discussion page setting of wordpress. However, I'm using a paywall plugin which uses gravatar (called memberful) and its account popup always shows the profile avatar regardless if its disabled or not on the discussion page.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the profile-window is actually an iframe...
To here: https://dylogue.memberful.com/account/subscriptions

Do you have access to this endpoint, or is it created by a script? Changing the general CSS wont help you if you do not have access to inserting css into this endpoint.

The stylesheets are in weird places:
https://d1zgk03a9fsd43.cloudfront.net/assets/reach/style-4556bac86321e164130eb81bc9c1bd3e8ad4f00e3a7f1b803ef1e7e272baf184.css
https://d1zgk03a9fsd43.cloudfront.net/packs/member-bafbfb186fc0b252fb994416a369b793.css

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the link to create an account and test this, but does this CSS work?

```
.memberful-account-header img {
     display: none; 
}
.memberful-account-header hgroup * {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope this was the code Raj & i tried. 
This popout is handled by memberful plugin. looking at the style it seems like it's from https://d1zgk03a9fsd43.cloudfront.net/assets/reach/style-4556bac86321e164130eb81bc9c1bd3e8ad4f00e3a7f1b803ef1e7e272baf184.css. I am not sure if we can actually remove it on local.
Can you help us? Let me share you a test account.  
Username: rajdeepsh@outlook.com  
password:  rajdeep

Comment: It’s 12:05am here—I’ll get to it in the morning :) thanks for the detail tho

Comment: alright, thanks man :) you should be able to see the account tab once logged in

Comment: Sorry for being late, but what CSS file are you adding this to? I edited my answer to remove the margin on the left for the name as well.

Comment: I just added into the "Additional CSS" option in wordpress Customization page

Comment: Hmm does anything change at all? @TsuWeiQuan

Comment: Nope. When i click the Account Tab, the picture appears as if it was being called from somewhere.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Try appending this code to the file at `{{wordpress-root}}/wp-content/plugins/wp-latest-posts/css/wplp_front.css`.

Comment: Yes i have access. It still doesn't work. Hmm may i ask why we have to put in wplp_front.css instead of memberful plugin subfolder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174916/discussion-between-samyok-nepal-and-tsu-wei-quan).